# 'self' scripts being blocked from loading, but when I use the nonce they work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, content-security-policy, nonce

There is probably a simple solution to this, but I can't figure it out.

I have a CSP defined like so:

```
"Content-Security-Policy: default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com fonts.googleapis.com; script-src www.google-analytics.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'self' 'nonce-". $_SESSION['nonce'] . "'; img-src * 'self' data:;object-src 'self' sias.dev:8000; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src 'self' sias.dev:8000 www.google.com;"
```

The CSP needs to be tweaked a little but is partially working.  I need a nonce because I have some legacy sites that have some inline scripts.  The nonce is generated dynamically and changed on page loads.  However, I ran into an issue where I'm loading some 'self' scripts on a page called via AJAX (not inline, but script src tags.  That is probably bad practice, but I don't want to load those except for the page called via ajax.

The strange thing is that I don't have any inline scripts on that page, just script src tags like below, where the nonce is dynamic and matches that in the CSP policy.

```
<script nonce = "" src="/js/create_dicom/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script nonce = "" src="/js/create_dicom/js/jquery.ui.plupload.min.js"></script>
<script nonce = "" src="/js/create_dicom/js/main.js"></script>
<script nonce = "" src="/bower/pdfjs/src/pdf.js"></script>
<script nonce = "" src="/bower/pdfjs/src/pdf.worker.js"></script>
```

When I don't use a nonce, I get:

```
"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)."
```

When I do use a nonce they load fine and the page works.  I thought that you only needed a nonce for inline scripts and not 'self' script.  Should I be using strict-dynamic somehow ?  I don't need a nonce in the main page for script-src tags.  They load fine there ?

Also, the places that I need a nonce are mostly on pages that are loaded via AJAX.  Is there are way to refactor things (i.e. putting them in .js files and loading the relevant .js that way).  That is kind of a pain because I don't have a script loader and I'd want to load just the relevant js for files loaded via AJAX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Console err: `The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at INLINE` says then you definitely have an inline script blocked not external, therefore it's nothing to do with 'self'. You can look al right console corner and see **script_name:line_number:column** where it happens.
   In case of lock externall script, the err looks like: `The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at HTTPS://EXAMPLE.COM/PATH/SCRIPT.JS`.
2. Could be 3 kinds of [inline scripts](https://csplite.com/csp147/#inline_script-src): `<script>...<script>`, `<a href='javascript:void(0)'` and `<a onclick='evtHandler()'`. Firefox does not distinguish these, Chrome is more verbose, so see how it looks this error in Chrome browser.
   There are 2 options:
     `-` there is NO error in Chrome - this is good, FF is known by [false positive](https://csplite.com/csp/test297/) violations
     `-` there is error in Chrome - you have an inline script and Chrome will say which exactly.
3. Tweak CSP via browser console log is bad practice. You use `pdf.min.js`, but this script contains a piece of code:

`const n = document.createElement("script");`
`n.src = e;`
`n.onload = t;`
`n.onerror = function() {`
    `r(new Error("Cannot load script at: " + n.src))`
`};`
`(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(n)`

which means that some external scripts could be loaded on some conditions. Only God knows what yoy need to press to occur that and from where this script will be loaded.
 Therefore a right way (if site have a visitors) is to use the `report-uri` directive and analyse a violation reports while about 2 weeks.

> 

PS: Just curious - you specify: `connect-src * 'unsafe-inline';` so you do have inline scripts somewhere? By the way, 'unsafe-inline' token is not used in the `connect-src` directive, it will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks.  Mistake with connect-src.  I may just slowly refactor the code so that I do not need nonces.  For now, mostly working, but I do have an issue when using multiple tabs because a new nonce is generating with every page load, so the 2 tabs will have different nonces, and the AJAX requests don't work then.  If I use a single nonce per session, not a problem, but it is when they are generated with every page load.  Might have to just refactor so it is not an issue.

Comment: If you do not change code between `<script>...</script>` oftenly, the 'sha256-value' token will be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script .  It auto allows inline script if its hash presents in script-src directive. Chrome browser auto calcs hashes for all inline scripts blocked, just look into console: `Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-RealHashIsHere'), or a nonce ('nonce -...') is required to enable inline execution`. And you can use and 'sha25-value' and 'nonce-value' at the same time.

Comment: Works either way.  The scripts are largely static, so using a hash is the lazy way to avoid putting them in separate .js files.  I would end up with  quite a few hashes to put in my CSP.  It that a performance problem, or is there a limited tot he size of headers (apparenlty 4-8K !  would never get close to that).